# JQuery validate working with "required", but not minlength or maxlength

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Jquery validate to perform client-side validation:
The form is inside of an .ascx ... required is working, but I cannot get minlength or maxlength to work. Is there something missing in my code. I am using the "name" of the

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#form1").validate({
            rules: {
                curPass: {
                    required: true
                },
                NwPass: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 8,
                    maxlength: 16
                },
                cfmPass: {
                    required: true
                }
            }

        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body id="body" style="background-image:url(http://www.regmovies.com/~/media/Images/Site%20Takeovers/wallpaper_cloudyNP.ashx);">


    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>         
    <RCC:RCCChgPass runat="server" ID="ChgPass" />
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Which `validate` plugin are you using (there are many?); do you know for sure it does support that option at all?

Comment: Any chance we could see the form?

Comment: this is the plugin: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="NewPass" name="nwPass" runat="server" TextMode="Password" CssClass="required"></asp:TextBox>   <br />

Comment: btw: I realize the name in NewPass ...nwPass is NwPass in the script, I corrected already, but the code still does not work.

Comment: I suspect this is due to your encoding. Have it working using your code at http://hypxr.com/test.html

Comment: you mean because it is in an .ascx and not a regular html form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the name property in the generated HTML is not what you expect it to be so the validation rules don't apply to the textboxes. Check it in the browser. The required validation works because of the assigned css class. Remove your validator JS code and check it again, I would expect it still validate against required

Comment: Still suspicious about the name property. Could you check the generated names in the html?

Comment: you are right, it generated something completely different. Hopefully, I can work get around this... thanks so much

Comment: That raises the question how the required works :) When I asked you to remove the validation JS code I meant only your script, but not the jquery.validate script. Anyway. Good luck with the name property, it was asked many times here on stackoverflow.

Comment: I used the name that was generated by the HTML, and I learned a lesson about not just assuming ... but my colleagues here said I should use the type: clientside... so I am going to check that out, as this is for a client and I want to do it right. Thanks so much!!

Comment: I think what you are using is good but you could have used rangeLength method. It would have done the same and would have saved a call to one method. it is used like rangeLength:[8,16] // both values are inclusive.